# How to make a try block within a loop?

Tags: java, loops, try-catch

I just learned about the *'try'* statement in **Java**, and what I'm trying to do is to have this input loop until the user's input is both an integer and a positive one.

This is my code so far:

```
int scanning () {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input = 0;
    boolean loop = false;
        do {
            try {
                System.out.print("Amount: ");
                input = scan.nextInt();
                if (input < 0) {
                    System.out.println("Error. Invalid amount entered.");
                    loop = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error: Invalid input");
                loop = true;
            }
        } while (loop);

    return input;
}
```

However it goes through an infinite loop when the user inputs an invalid integer, printing the error message over and over. The expected outcome is to keep asking the user for a valid input.

Comment: Please post the code here, not an image

Comment: you simply need to call `nextLine` in case of an exception to catch the carriage return. By the way, the code in your image differs from your code posted here.

Comment: Cant find any try/catch block in your code?

Comment: Updated. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You do realize that with `scan.nextInt()` you are not getting a user input.

Comment: @MuratK. What do he get instead?

Comment: @Tom The scanned input.

Comment: @MuratK. Which is the user input (if it was a number). So it is still unclear what you mean with "not getting a user input".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset the value of `loop` variable in the `do-while` loop before each time just before checking the condition.

```
do {
  try {
    System.out.print("Amount: ");
    input = scan.nextInt();
    loop = false;             // Reset the variable here.
    if (input < 0) {
      System.out.println("Error. Invalid amount entered.");
      loop = true;
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error: Invalid input");
    scan.next();             // This is to consume the new line character from the previous wrong input.
    loop = true;
  }
} while (loop);
```

Answer (score 2):

This code will help you to be in infinite loop and also throw a exception when input is a -ve integer.

The exception handling in java is one of the powerful mechanism to handle the runtime errors so that normal flow of the application can be maintained.

Most of the times when we are developing an application in java, we often feel a need to create and throw our own exceptions.So first create a user defined exception AmountException.

```
      public class AmountException extends Exception {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public AmountException() {
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                System.out.println("Error. Invalid amount entered");
            }
        }
```

And now edit your scanning() to this :

```
    int scanning () {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input = 0;
    boolean loop = false;
    do {
        try {
            System.out.print("Amount: ");
            input = scan.nextInt();
            if (input < 0) {

                loop = true;
                throw new AmountException();

            } else {
                loop = false;
            }

        } catch (AmountException e) {

        }
    } while (loop);

    return input;
}
```

Comment: How does this help? It also doesn't solve OPs problem.

Answer (score 0):

From you code, Change loop to false and when the valid input is given, it will terminate the `while` loop

```
boolean loop = false;
    do {
        try {
            loop = false;
            System.out.print("Amount: ");
            input = scan.nextInt();
            if (input < 0) {
                System.out.println("Error. Invalid amount entered.");
                loop = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: Invalid input");
            loop = true;
        }
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. I inserted the wrong code without the try block. I updated the question with the right one, though.

Comment: if you break then it will return wrong input from the method.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `else` block after `if`, otherwise, `loop` will always stay `true` if the first input is invalid.

```
if (input < 0) {
    System.out.println("Error. Invalid amount entered.");
    loop = true;
} else {
    loop = false;
}
```